# Storing data in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am building a basic latin translator in Prolog. I have data which I currently store in this format as predicates:

```
noun("femin","femin",1,"f",translation("woman","women")).

verb("port", "portare", "portav", "portat", 1, translation("carry","carrying","carried")).

nounending("ae","with",sg).
```

I would rather use something like a spreadsheet to input the nouns and verbs. I have thought of parsing a .csv to a .pl but this is an unwieldy solution. Is there a way to easily input predicates in SWI-Prolog using a spreadsheet-like application?

Comment: Is the import of the bulk of nouns and verbs a one-time event, and then just light maintenance after that? Maybe you just need a one-time conversion of your existing noun/verb database into prolog syntax, and then just maintain the prolog after that (assuming you aren't using the database as an infeed to other needs). But I think @CapelliC has the right idea for handing the CSV. Look up the SWI Prolog CSV library predicates.

Comment: Yes this is a one time conversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would rather use something like a spreadsheet to input the nouns and verbs.

A spreadsheet is a *great* way to describe live, functional relations among Entities, but I fear you will have to bite-the-bullet and go the unwieldy way, reading CSV.

Is not that bad, SWI-Prolog for instance has a [CSV library](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=csv), or you could use it as a case study (assuming you're interested in Prolog) and write your own DCG. A much rewarding exercise...

Another possibility, if you can write a bit of code on Spreadsheet side, you could output spreadsheet' cells in Prolog format:

```
cell(1,1,'Hello').
cell(1,2,'World').
```

Or consider that any relational editor (your preferred 'Db Admin tool') could be useful to input tabular data, and since then you access it using your Prolog RDB interface (like ODBC).

Note: a spreadsheet is usually easy to save in a table. Then access via RDB is granted.

*edit* It come to my mind that after saving the table (as SQL dump), pack(prosqlite) -in SWI-Prolog - will grant you access to your most valuable cells :)

Comment: So you suggest I write a program to parse the .csv into .pl? (e.g femin,femin,1,f,woman,women,. -> noun("femin","femin",1,f,"woman","women"). My understanding of a DCG seems irrelevant to what is at task here? I have absolutely no idea about databases (I'm not really sure what IS a database). Could you clarify what you mean by your edit? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: no, first check CSV SWI-Prolog library. If you see fit, use that. See my edited post, I've added a link

Comment: a database is a collection of tables, i.e. spreadsheets where *all* rows have the *same* number of columns.